# Can you repeatedly split a PDF after a Keyword in Java using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, split, pdfbox

I would like to split a PDF into multiple PDFs by searching for a ceartain word, similar to java.lang.String#split(String) using [PDFBox](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox).

Is there a way to split a document A

| A |
| --- |
| This is a line |
| This is another line |
| This is the line I want to use for the split |
|  |
| This is a regular line again |
| This is a regular line as well |
| Here I'd like to do another split |
| This should be the first line of the third document |

So that if I'd used the parameter value "split" it would be split into three documents like so:

| A.0 |
| --- |
| This is a line |
| This is another line |
| This is the line I want to use for the split |

| A.1 |
| --- |
|  |
| This is a regular line again |
| This is a regular line as well |
| Here I'd like to do another split |

| A.2 |
| --- |
| This should be the first line of the third document |

Comment: Not really, PDF isn't like HTML. You could copy it and then modify the cropbox, but you'd still have the same content when doing text extraction.

Comment: Do you want to apply this to arbitrary pdfs? Or only to specific pdfs which all are generated alike? In the latter case please provide a representative example PDF to analyze; if its internal structures are easy enough to separate, such a split may be implemented in the scope of an answer here. In the former case, though, we're clearly beyond that scope for a clean implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your promt answer, it helped me already by giving me direction.
The former case would be my goal. 
But if the documents structure is more complex, i'll have to find a different solution.